# HttpRuntime.Cache Equivalent for asp.net 5, MVC 6

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-4.5

So I've just moved from ASP.Net 4 to ASP.Net 5. Im at the moment trying to change a project so that it works in the new ASP.Net but of course there is going to be a load of errors.

Does anyone know what the equivalent extension is for HttpRuntime as I cant seem to find it anywhere. I'm using to cache an object client side.

```
HttpRuntime.Cache[Findqs.QuestionSetName]
```

'Findqs' is just a general object

Comment: Check the [in memory cache](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/caching.html?highlight=cache#in-memory-caching) in the asp docs. For distributed caching, the docs are still uncomplete. You might find something in the samples of the new [asp 5 caching repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/tree/dev/samples)

Comment: The accepted answer shows another way to do it, but **I just posted a way to do it exactly how you asked for**. In other words, it's possible to use an equivalent of `HttpRuntime.Cache["key"] ` on asp.net core, and my answer shows how to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can an `IMemoryCache` implementation for caching data. There are different implementations of this including an in-memory cache, redis,sql server caching etc..

Quick and simple implemenation goes like this

Update your `project.json` file and add the below 2 items under `dependencies` section.

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Saving this file will do a dnu restore and the needed assemblies will be added to your project.

Go to Startup.cs class, enable caching by calling the `services.AddCaching()` extension method in `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCaching();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Now you can inject `IMemoryCache` to your class via constructor injection. The framework will resolve a concrete implementation for you and inject it to your class constructor.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IMemoryCache memoryCache;
    public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {   
        var existingBadUsers = new List<int>();
        var cacheKey = "BadUsers";
        List<int> badUserIds = new List<int> { 5, 7, 8, 34 };
        if(memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out existingBadUsers))
        {
            var cachedUserIds = existingBadUsers;
        }
        else
        {
            memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, badUserIds);
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Ideally you do not want to mix your caching within your controller. You may move it to another class/layer to keep everything readable and maintainable. You can still do the constructor injection there.

The official asp.net mvc [repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/tree/dev/samples) has more samples for your reference.

Comment: this is great! Thank you

Answer (score 11):

<sub>My answer is focused on the "Does anyone know what the equivalent extension is for HttpRuntime as I cant seem to find it anywhere"</sub>

You tagged two different frameworks (.net and .net core), and for them there are two completely different caching implementations/solutions. The first one below is the one you were looking for:

1 - `System.Runtime.Caching/MemoryCache`
2 - `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/IMemoryCache`

**System.Runtime.Caching/MemoryCache:**
This is pretty much the same as the old day's ASP.Net MVC's `HttpRuntime.Cache`. **You can use it on ASP.Net CORE without any dependency injection**. This is how to use it:

```
// First install 'System.Runtime.Caching' (NuGet package)

// Add a using
using System.Runtime.Caching;

// To get a value
var myString = MemoryCache.Default["itemCacheKey"];

// To store a value
MemoryCache.Default["itemCacheKey"] = myString;
```

**Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory**
This one is tightly coupled with Dependency Injection, and is the recommended way to do it on ASP.Net CORE. This is **one** way to implement it:

```
// In asp.net core's Startup add this:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

Using it on a controller:

```
// Add a using
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

// In your controller's constructor, you add the dependency on the 'IMemoryCache'
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;
    public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        // To get a value
        string myString = null;
        if (_cache.TryGetValue("itemCacheKey", out myString))
        { /*  key/value found  -  myString has the key cache's value*/  }


        // To store a value
        _cache.Set("itemCacheKey", myString);
    }
}
```